# Javascript inside window submit method stopped working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was using window.open method to map my form and appending few elements to window.

Now once I do this I need to submit the form.
I am using this to submit the form, once window.open works, elements are binded I need to submit it.
But somehow it is not submitting the form, I tried several ways but alas I couldnt find one. It stopped working on my live site today itself?

Here is my code:

```
win = window.open("", "", "height=" + height + ",width=" + width +",status=yes")
    if (win != null)
    {
      win.document.open('text/html')
      win.document.write("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>text Order Submission</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>")
      win.document.write(content)
      win.document.write("</BODY></HTML>")
      win.document.close()
    }

if (win) {
      // Hide popblock.
      document.getElementById('popblock').style.visibility = 'hidden';

      // Copy over information, using getElementsByTagName if available, and old-style
      // code if it isn't.
      form = win.document.custform;  
      if (document.getElementsByTagName)  {
        elements = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for( i=0; elm=elements.item(i); i++) {
          if (elm.getAttribute('type') == "hidden")  {
            //alert("Setting " + elm.name + "  to " + window.document.getElementById(elm.name).value);
            elm.value = (window.document.getElementById(elm.name)) ? window.document.getElementById(elm.name).value : '';
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        // Actually looking through more elements here but the result is the same.
        elements = form.elements;
        for( i=0; elm=elements[i]; i++)  {
          if (elm.type == "hidden") {
            elm.value = (window.document.getElementById(elm.name)) ? window.document.getElementById(elm.name) : '';
          }
        }
      }

      // Submit custform to orderprep.php
      win.document.custform.submit();
```

Issue is my elements do get bind but form is not submitting, Anything wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

The window is loading asynchronously, but you're not waiting for its DOM to load. You need to run the code at the bottom in the window's `load` event listener.

```js
let win = window.open("", "", "height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",status=yes")
if (win) {
  win.document.open('text/html')
  win.document.write("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>text Order Submission</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>")
  win.document.write(content)
  win.document.write("</BODY></HTML>")
  win.document.close()
  win.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // Hide popblock.
    document.getElementById('popblock').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    // Copy over information, using getElementsByTagName if available, and old-style
    // code if it isn't.
    let form = win.document.custform;
    let elm;
    if (document.getElementsByTagName) {
      let elements = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
      for (let i = 0; elm = elements.item(i); i++) {
        if (elm.getAttribute('type') == "hidden") {
          //alert("Setting " + elm.name + "  to " + window.document.getElementById(elm.name).value);
          elm.value = (window.document.getElementById(elm.name)) ? window.document.getElementById(elm.name).value : '';
        }
      }
    } else {
      // Actually looking through more elements here but the result is the same.
      let elements = form.elements;
      for (let i = 0; elm = elements[i]; i++) {
        if (elm.type == "hidden") {
          elm.value = (window.document.getElementById(elm.name)) ? window.document.getElementById(elm.name) : '';
        }
      }
    }

    // Submit custform to orderprep.php
    win.document.custform.submit()
  });
}
```

You should also remember to declare all your variables as local variables.